# Request Microsoft Graph Token with App password

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I try to get a token from a Post Request to https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token by using a App Password I generated in order to skip the 2FA. I tryed this using the grant_type "password" but I get an error saying that my username/password combination is invalid. I assume that I'm using the wrong grant_type for the request.

Is there a different grant_type that I have to use with App password than with normal password?

Comment: Have you checked this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58200571/can-i-use-mfa-app-passwords-with-azure-oauth2-0-ropc).

Comment: Are you still looking for help here?