# How to pass MFA enabled Azure account credentials into PowerShell ScriptBlock?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-powershell, scriptblock, powershell-jobs

connect-azuread | out-null

$global:token = [Microsoft.Open.Azure.AD.CommonLibrary.AzureSession]::AccessTokens

$ceo = "<ceo_username>"

Import-Csv "C:\Users\abhilash\Music\users.txt" | ForEach-Object  {

$scriptblock = {

param($userprincipalname)

Connect-Azuread -AadAccessToken $global:token.AccessToken.AccessToken -accountid <my_username>

New-Object PSObject -property @{

Manager1 = $l = (Get-AzureADUserManager -ObjectId $userprincipalname).userprincipalname      
Manager2 = $m = if ($l -ne $null -and $l -ne $CEO) { (Get-AzureADUserManager -ObjectId $l).userprincipalname } else { $null } 
Manager3 = $n = if ($m -ne $null -and $m -ne $CEO) { (Get-AzureADUserManager -ObjectId $m).userprincipalname } else { $null }  
Manager4 = $o = if ($n -ne $null -and $n -ne $CEO) { (Get-AzureADUserManager -ObjectId $n).userprincipalname } else { $null }

}  | Select @{N='User';E={$userprincipalname}},Manager1,Manager2,manager3,manager4

}

Start-Job $ScriptBlock -ArgumentList $_

}

While (Get-Job -State "Running") {  Start-Sleep 10 }

Get-job| receive-job

---

"You must call the Connect-AzureAD cmdlet before calling any other cmdlets" ...... I get this error even after having active session, tried connecting with accesstoken, now I get error as "Cannot validate argument on parameter 'AadAccessToken'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again."

Answer (score 0):

We have tried with your given code and its asking for users to add their credential for authentication.

***AFAIK, we can not pass the MFA enabled azure account credential in PowerShell script.***

So we have  to use the `cmdlets` to connect our services without using parameter Credential. This will show us the Sign in to our account popup (log-in window)of the services which has the support for MFA as below. We have provide the user account name in `ceo` and `my username`.
[image]

For more information please refer this [***BLOG***](https://www.portiva.nl/portiblog/blogs-cat/using-mfa-enabled-accounts-in-powershell-scripts) & [***SO THREAD***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58200571/can-i-use-mfa-app-passwords-with-azure-oauth2-0-ropc)

Comment: Hello Ajay, the purpose of the script is to get the manager hierarchy till CEO for the imported users. I have connected to tenant by providing my credentials and satisfying MFA but still the script is asking to enter credential for every imported user from the list in the script block. .... How do I make use of the existing session ? if that's not possible, how can I use the AccessToken to connect tenant silently without any interaction inside the scriptblock?